# Illustration of Arithmetic operations in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I m having 3 text boxes named FirstNumber,SecondNumber and ThirdNumber and three radio buttons for operation selection.when a certain radio button is clicked a certain result is displayed in a label. However unless I enter the numbers into the text boxes before running the program the results come out as 0. i tried to do this through the following code, but am not getting the expected result, suggest some tips fix this?

```
Dim FirstNumber As Integer
Dim SecondNumber As Integer
Dim ThirdNumber As Integer
Dim Result1 As Integer
Dim Result2 As Integer
Dim Result3 As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FirstNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    SecondNumber = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    ThirdNumber = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    Result1 = FirstNumber + SecondNumber - ThirdNumber
    Result2 = FirstNumber - ThirdNumber / SecondNumber
    Result3 = SecondNumber Mod ThirdNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: if you do not need to get those values from a user, use a variable instead of a TextBox...or type in some values

Comment: I want the user to type in the values for the three numbers, but when I type in values the result is just 0

Comment: how do you determine that the result is zero?  your calculations are being done the first time the form loads LONG before a user could enter anything.  You may have used the wrong event.  add a button and move that code to the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Form_Load` runs when the `Form` is being loaded, and that is before you can event see the it. The `TextBox`es are still empty at the time.

You should place your code inside (for example) a `Click` event on a `Button` added to your form. Then enter text into the TextBoxes and click the button to see the results.

```
Dim FirstNumber As Integer
Dim SecondNumber As Integer
Dim ThirdNumber As Integer
Dim Result1 As Integer
Dim Result2 As Integer
Dim Result3 As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FirstNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    SecondNumber = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    ThirdNumber = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    Result1 = FirstNumber + SecondNumber - ThirdNumber
    Result2 = FirstNumber - ThirdNumber / SecondNumber
    Result3 = SecondNumber Mod ThirdNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

move the code from the Form1_Load to a sub, then call the sub when you need it...for example, when the user changes values in the textboxes.

```
Private Sub doCalculation()
    FirstNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    SecondNumber = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    ThirdNumber = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    Result1 = FirstNumber + SecondNumber - ThirdNumber
    Result2 = FirstNumber - ThirdNumber / SecondNumber
    Result3 = SecondNumber Mod ThirdNumber
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    call doCalculation()
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `Call` keyword anymore.

Comment: ...what will happen when they are typing in TB1 and there is nothing in TB2?  use a button

Comment: well, that was to get you started, I assumed you could work it out from there. If TB2 is nothing, you're correct, it won't work. So you'll need some validation functionality in the doCalculation (check for all textbox values before calculating) or error handling (try/catch)

Comment: OneFineDay: true, you don't need to use `Call`, I still use it many times just so it stands out when I'm looking at the code.

Comment: What about the radio button mentioned in the question, by Todd432

Comment: Sujith: I have no idea what he's doing with the radio buttons or labels he described. He didn't post any code for that.

Comment: @ Chase Rocker : you are absolutely wrong, this code will not give a result and throws `DivisionByZero Exception`. it is because, when the value of text1 is changed before enter a value to the text2 result in `secondNumber=0` hence the snippet  ` Result2 = FirstNumber - ThirdNumber / SecondNumber` throws the exception.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: If you read my comments above, I answer that. My answer was to get him started, not a complete solution. I explained he needs to add validation functionality and/or error handling.

Comment: @ Chase Rocker : i just informed that the snippet given by you will throw arithmetic exception

Comment: @SujithKarivelil it won't throw an exception if all the textboxes have values. That's why in my comment above, I explained he needs to validate them.

Comment: a `Try/Catch` is very expensive and not really error handling.  Error handling is code like `If CInt(TextBox2.Text) <> 0 Then...` used to avoid exceptions; much of which is not needed if you arent trying to perform calculations every single time the user presses a key.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code corresponds to the question which having all the functions asked in the question:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub doCalculation(ByVal op As Integer)
        Dim FirstNumber As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim SecondNumber As Integer = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim ThirdNumber As Integer = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
        Dim Result As Integer
        If SecondNumber = 0 Then
            MsgBox("unable to proceed.. Second text box cannot be left blank")
            TextBox2.Focus
        Else
        Select Case op
            Case 0 : Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber - ThirdNumber
            Case 1 : Result = FirstNumber - ThirdNumber / SecondNumber
            Case 2 : Result = SecondNumber Mod ThirdNumber
        End Select
        MsgBox(Result)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub moduls_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles moduls.Click
        doCalculation(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub addsub_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addsub.Click
        doCalculation(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub subdiv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles subdiv.Click
        doCalculation(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

where **subdiv,addsub and moduls** are radio buttons

Comment: almost.  what if TextBox2 is empty or "0" and they click RB0/AddSub?

Comment: @  Plutonix :see this code ` If SecondNumber = 0 Then
            SecondNumber = 1
        End If`

Comment: @ Plutonix: See the upates